# How to make hairline around vector graphic?

Tags: vector, svg, scribus

I wanted to render a Scribus .sla file to .pdf and got a warning .pdf embedded. The reason was that I placed a .pdf graphic in an image frame instead of importing it as vector file.

An internet search revealed that .pdf graphics are in fact pixelated if imported as images (or when selecting wrong option); therefore the warning. So I imported a .pdf as well as a .svg of my graphic using *File >> Import >> Get Vector File...* and placed it on my document―so far so good.

However I need a hairline around the graphic, i.e. a thin box; this works well with image frames. But for some reason with the "Vector File frame" the options are greyed out:

[image]

When I double-click on the graphic, a window opens with an option "edit contour line", but that's something different. I probably could draw a box around the graphic by hand, but I think there might be a better option.

So, how can I make a hairline (or any thin line) around my vector graphic?

I'm using Scribus 1.5.8 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

***Update:*** Just realized that I would run into a follow-up problem, because I want to place another graphic exactly under the first one (it's the legend) and draw the box around both. Perhaps the vector objects should be put together in kind of a frame or so, but I still don't know how.

Comment: PDFs can contain both vector and raster graphics.  Might be better to use Inkscape - which is a vector image editor - you can export as PDF or save as SVG. Scribus is just page layout software.

Comment: @BillyKerr Not sure if I understand the point of your comment. Even when importing a .pdf as vector file in Scribus, I can't make a line around the frame as well. Drawing a line in different software is no option, this should be a layout job.

Comment: What does the graphic look like? What kind of "frame" or outline are you talking about?  Is it just a rectangle?  You can draw rectangles in Scribus and group them with your graphic. If it's more complex, like going around a graphic, I'd use a vector image editor, and import it into Scribus for layout only.  Using different software for different purposes is something that graphic designers do all the time.

Comment: @BillyKerr It can be a plot or a table for instance, I can place and scale it like an image, but cannot use the stroke feature to make the box visible. With images I just click on a stroke color and have my box, no need to draw a rectangle, know what I mean?

Comment: Sorry, not really. Can you show an example image?  An example of what you want to do, or what has failed

Comment: I'm not a Scribus user..  I can't help but wonder.. You can't merely *draw a rectangle in Scribus*? Or.. are you wanting this "outline" to conform to the graphic? If that's they case, you do that in the *drawing* app, not the layout app. Even Indesign can't draw an outline which conforms to a placed graphic.

Comment: @Scott - you definitely can. Not sure what the problem is here to be honest. I think the OP needs to add more information.

Comment: @BillyKerr So, here are examples of a [plot](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336016606/figure/fig2/AS:960032011202568@1605900876067/Scatter-plot-of-the-predicted-values-of-pEC50-vs-experimental-values-by-MLR-model-for.png) and a [table](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Markus-Hofmann-5/publication/326976047/figure/tbl2/AS:669174099615746@1536554946134/Linear-mixed-effects-model-results-for-the-exploratory-analyses.png). Really nothing special. Think to have them as vector files to be able to scale them without loss.

Comment: Jay.. just draw a rectangle around them in Scribus, then group the graphic with the rectangle. Am I missing something? While most layout apps will allow you to merely add a stroke to a [placed] graphic's "frame" perhaps Scribus simply doesn't. For example, if one were to copy/paste a vector graphic into InDesign.. the only way to add an "outline" or border around the graphic would be to draw a secondary rectangle within InDesign, then group it with the graphic.

Comment: I would just draw a rectangle with the Insert Shape tool. Set the line width to hairline.  [see example](https://imgur.com/Se5M1PD). Then group the rectangle and graphic if you want to move them together as one object.

Comment: @BillyKerr I tried to condense your great suggestions in an answer, thanks very much.

Comment: @Scott I tried to condense your great suggestions in an answer, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

When we import a vector file in a Scribus document, we actually import paths. Adding a rectangled frame around the paths is not trivial and probably therefore not implemented (also in other layout software).

A professional option (as also suggested in comments from *@billy-kerr* and  *@scott*) is to draw a rectangle, i.e. do *Insert >> Shape >> Default Shapes >> <rectangle symbol>*. Next, in *Properties* panel, give the rectangle desired fill and stroke from the *Colors* menu. Next import vector file as shown in OP and place/scale it on the rectangle as desired. Finally, right-click and group both.

Comment: @jay_sf - Cool. +1 from me!!

Comment: +1 me too. Its how it often needs to be handled if the graphic itself doesn't have a "frame" that's accessible.

Comment: Perhaps useless info..... This actually has a great deal to do with how "accessible" the graphic itself is within the layout app. i.e. if it's possible in the layout app (Scribus/InDesign) to select individual elements *within* the graphic, it means the vectors are *more accessible* in the layout app. This often means there's no "frame" because the elements are part of the native layout and not seen as an external link. So there's actually *added* benefit to the way the graphic is seen in the layout, but one sacrifices the "frame" aspect of standard linked graphics.

Comment: Don't forget to come back soon and choose your own answer as best!!